# In Firebase, I'm getting ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT when trying to create a short dynamic link via REST

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-dynamic-links, google-iam

I want to create a [short dynamic link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) via the REST API. My goal is to create a short link with a custom URL suffix.

First, I created an auth token with the following command:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token
```

Then, I sent the request:

```
POST https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/managedShortLinks:create
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{auth_token}}

{
    "longDynamicLink": "https://example.com/l/?efr=0&ibi=abc&isi=def&apn=ghi&link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fl%2Fcustom-short-link",
    "suffix": {
        "customSuffix": "custom-suffix",
        "option": "CUSTOM"
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2022 02:21:07 GMT
Server: ESF
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.firebase.dynamiclinks.v1.DynamicLinksService.CreateManagedShortLink",
          "service": "firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried using my personal account and service account with the `Firebase Dynamic Links Admin` role. It is not working. Any ideas?